# How can I get data from my kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect

Whenever I try using `openni_launch`, it works normally, however, when I try viewing an image using the kinect's rgb or depth camera, or even recording a simple `bagfile` with data from the kinect, I am unable to see any picture and `rosbag` does not record any data, and after a few seconds of running `image_view` or `rosbag record`, I got this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.8-0precise-20130418-2203/src/openni_device.cpp @ 224 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 3788, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
```

After searching around and trying various fixes, I figured it might be a problem with openni and started using freenect, however I encountered the same problems, I could not record any data using bagfiles or see any images from the kinect (using `rviz` or `image_view`)

Then someone asked me to use something completely unrelated, `freenect-glview`, however that too gave me a black screen.

`lsusb` shows that all 3 parts of the kinect are connected and I've been able to control the kinect's motor through ubuntu so I know that there is at least a connection established between both.

Additional Info:

- I run ROS on Ubuntu using VirtualBox V.4.2.14 and Windows 7 with USB 2 ports
- I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ROS-Groovy (all up to date)
- I've had the exact same errors on my Mac OSX Lion
- When I try using Rviz with the kinect, VirtualBox crashes all together

I would appreciate anyone's help on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out VirtualBox was causing everything to not work properly for some reason. Now I'm using VMware and everything's running fine. What confused me was that I was getting errors that I found online and that even after trying every fix I could find some would still be there. Next step is getting XYZ coordinates of a moving robot, I'll start looking for tutorials right away (I'm still new to ros).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what VMware is doing correctly that VirtualBox was not?

Comment: I don't know what exactly was the problem but the result was that I was unable to view any images from the kinect or acquire any depth/rgb data from it even though I was able to control the motor just fine. When I switched to VMware it worked perfectly fine with `freenect`. `Openni` still has a few hiccups but I can make it work on VMware too.